# NotificationHub in Xamarin form: How to tell is the notification has been sent

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I am using NotificationHub to send a basic pending booking message to devices which have a tag of tag_12.

```
var apsOutcome = await PushNotification(Apple, tag, siteId, message);
if (apsOutcome.Success > 0)
{
  siteBookings.BookingList.ForEach(y => y.IsApsSend = true);
}
```

I am able to use it to send the message but not sure how the NotificationOutcome works.

I have data returned the NotificationOutcome.Success = 2 whereas some other data return Success = 0 and Failure = 0

What does 2 represent? Is it the NotificationOutcomeState.Process, but what about the NotificationOutcomeState.Completed.

```
 private async Task<NotificationOutcome> PushNotification(string pns, string tagExpression, int siteId, string message)
    { 
        var outcome = new NotificationOutcome();

        switch (pns)
        {
            case Apple:
                var payload1 = String.Format("\"alert\" : \"{0}\", \"siteId\": {1}, \"message\" : \"{2}\"", message, siteId, message);
                var apsPayload = String.Format("\"aps\" : {0}", "{"+payload1+"}" );
                outcome = await hubClient.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync("{"+apsPayload+"}", tagExpression);
                   break;
            case FireBase:
                var payload2 = "{" + String.Format("\"siteId\": {0}, \"message\" : \"{1}\" ", siteId, message) + "}";
                var fireBasePayload = "{" + String.Format("\"data\" : {0}", payload2) + "}";
                outcome = await hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(fireBasePayload, tagExpression);
                break;
        }

        return outcome;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think the NotificationOutcome.Success value mean the value of the messages's [NotificationOutcomeState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationoutcomestate?view=azure-dotnet) is Completed.

> Completed: NotificationOutcome when the notification sent has been recevied

It means "received by the corresponding push notification service". If it's an iOS device, it would be "received by APNS".